# Set a variable in url using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables, url

I need to set two variable in a url, $id and $job. The data should come from mysql select statement, [id] and [job_number_id]. My page displays a client job proposal and if there is more than one all proposals are displayed but the [id] and the [job_number_id] determines what is displayed on the webpage. I dont have a clue as to how this done. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost/estimate_lar/homepage.php';
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query =    "SELECT id, client_job_name, job_number_id
            FROM `job_name`
            WHERE `id`='$id'";
$allJobs = $db->query($query);

?>

<?php foreach ($allJobs as $site_title) : ?>
 <p> 
  <tr><?php echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$site_title['client_job_name'],$site_title['job_number_id']. '<br />'.'</a>'; ?>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is this the full code ? You are missing `session_start()` , database connection..

Comment: What error it is showing ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran the session_start() is located in another file. There are a few files more files that I didn't include. At this point I'm not receiving any errors because I haven't added a variable to the http address. I need to get the id and job number id and add it to the url.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the variables to be avaialble in the URL you need to read them with `$_GET`.

Getting the arguements from a url such as `index.php?id=1&job_number_id=3` will look like that:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['job_number_id'])) {//make sure both arguments are set
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $job_number_id = $_GET['job_number_id'];
}
```

To set it in your foreach statement:

```
<?php foreach ($allJobs as $site_title) : ?>
 <p> 
      <tr><?php 

$url = "http://localhost/estimate_lar/homepage.php?id=" . $site_title['id'] . "&job_number_id=" . $site_title['job_number_id'];

echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$site_title['client_job_name'],$site_title['job_number_id']. '<br />'.'</a>'; 

    ?>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

PLEASE remember to read about SQL injection and making sure you are escaping your inputs. Or even better - use a prepared statement.

Currently your script is volunerable, since everyone could just alter the URL and manipluate your DB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: After adding this code, I'm now getting a **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Before I had no errors, what happened?

Comment: It could be various reasons. Do var_dump($_GET) and post it so I can look. Also, are you using mysql, mysqli or pdo? do var_dump on $alljobs as well.

Comment: var_dump on $alljobs array(0) { } object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(76) "SELECT id, client_job_name, job_number_id FROM job_name WHERE id='8'" }

Comment: var_dump on ($_GET)    Notice: Undefined index: job_number_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Estimate_lar\home.php on line 33

Comment: the $_GET error is because you are not setting  job_number_id in the url

Comment: The first error happens because of the 2nd. If you are not suppling a job_number_id in the url, the query will not execute because of the IF statement. Either remove the condition or supply the argument in the url.

Comment: The $id needs to come from the $_SESSION['id'] and the job_number_id should come from mysql database job_name table. Not sure how that's done.

Comment: Just remove the IF statement I wrote and use the $_GET exampels I've given you when only when you need them. Your question was maybe not that clear but I think my answer helps resolve your problem and explain the basics of what you asked.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to get the job_number_id to equal the table job_name, job_number_id? Where you have job_number_id=3. That 3 should come from my job_name table.

Comment: @user3135712 take a look at the addition to my answer. It should explain how to construct the $url to include the variables in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$url = 'http://localhost/estimate_lar/homepage.php';
if($id){

$query =    "SELECT id, client_job_name, job_number_id  FROM `job_name`  WHERE `id`='$id'";
$allJobs = $db->query($query);

}else{
echo "Id not in session";
}
?>
 <table>
<?php if ($allJobs)  { foreach ($allJobs as $site_title) : ?>

  <tr>
  <td>
 <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?client_job_name=<?php echo $site_title['client_job_name'];?>&job_number_id=<?php echo $site_title['job_number_id'];?> "> <?php echo $site_title['job_number_id']. " ".$site_title['job_number_id']; ?></a>
  </td>

 </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

 <?php }else{ echo 'No results Found' ;} ?>
```

This may help you.